# Não consigo deixar palavras lado a lado do form

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Gostaria de deixar uma `div` completamente alinhada com um formulário de forma reta horizontalmente. Porém, embora estejam lado a lado, o formulário esta "descendo" quando deveria ficar alinhado horizontalmente. Como posso resolver esse problema? Atualmente está assim:

```css
#contato{
 background-color:#ABB7B7;
 margin-top:5%;
 width:100%;
 display: inline-block;
}

#frm{
 margin-left:35%;
}

#frm input[type="text"]{
 height:30px;
 width:60%;
 border:none;
}

#frm textarea{
 width:60%;
 border:none;
}

#frm input[type="submit"]{
 border:none;
 width:15%;
 height:30px;
 color:white;
 background-color:black;
 margin-left:45%;
}

#cont-ap{
 width:30%;
}
```

```html
  <div id="contato">
            <div id="cont-ap">
                <h3>Por favor, mande nos uma mensagem, fale conosco e tire todas as suas dúvidas.</h3>
            </div>
   <form action="#" method="POST" id="frm">
    <h3 id="msg"></h3>
    <input type="text" name="mailTxt" id="mailTxt" placeholder="Seu endereço de email aqui" onblur="validaEmail(this);" />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="text" name="assntTxt" id="assntTxt" placeholder="O assunto do seu email" onblur="validaAssunto(this);" />
    <br /><br />
    <textarea id="msgMail" placeholder="A sua mensagem" onblur="validaMsg(this);"></textarea>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="btnMail" id="btnMail" />
   </form>
  </div>
```

E aqui está o [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q8ue8x5o/1/).

Comment: Coloque o formulário dentro de um `<div>` e crie uma regra `#contato div { display: inline-block }`.

Comment: @renan não funcionou, continua embaixo...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/q8ue8x5o/2/

Comment: o problema é que dessa forma, metade do formulario fica "cortado" mesmo a width estando correta.

Comment: Aí o problema são as outras regras que colocou. Está cortando porque você ta limitando o `width` dos inputs: https://jsfiddle.net/q8ue8x5o/3/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/q8ue8x5o/8/

Answer (score 1):

O margin-left que você adicionou no `#frm input[type="submit"]` e no `#frm` ta fazendo ele quebra a linha. Mas se você deixar o id `#cont-ap` desse jeito resolve seu problema:

```css
#cont-ap{
  width:30%;
  float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dei uma alterada na estrutura do seu html e na forma como você construiu seu css.
Dividi a pagina em uma div `contato` e dentro desta coloquei mais duas div's `cont-ap` e `formulario`. Depois só ageitei o css colocando `display:inline-block` nos dois elementos internos e um `vertical-align: top` na div `cont-ap`.
Retirei também os `width's` dinâmicos, pois estava muito estranho o layout.

**Por fim ficou assim:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/q8ue8x5o/6/

Este possui as div's internas centralizadas

- https://jsfiddle.net/q8ue8x5o/7/

```css
#contato{
 background-color:#ABB7B7;
 margin-top:5%;
}

.formulario{
   display: inline-block;
    width:250px;
}


.formulario input[type="text"]{
 height:30px;
 width:250px;
 border:none;
}

.formulario textarea{
 width:250px;
 border:none;
}

.formulario input[type="submit"]{
 border:none;
 height:30px;
 color:white;
 background-color:black;
 float: right;

}

#cont-ap{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width:39%;
}
```

```html
  <div id="contato">
            <div id="cont-ap">
                <h3>Por favor, mande nos uma mensagem, fale conosco e tire todas as suas dúvidas.</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="formulario">
   <form action="#" method="POST" id="frm">
    <h3 id="msg"></h3>
    <input type="text" name="mailTxt" id="mailTxt" placeholder="Seu endereço de email aqui" onblur="validaEmail(this);" />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="text" name="assntTxt" id="assntTxt" placeholder="O assunto do seu email" onblur="validaAssunto(this);" />
    <br /><br />
    <textarea id="msgMail" placeholder="A sua mensagem" onblur="validaMsg(this);"></textarea>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="btnMail" id="btnMail" />
   </form>
      </div>
  </div>
```